# Make hudson respond to http://servername:8080/hudson

Tags: hudson

I am using the default hudson installation on windows as a service. It is listening on the 8080 port and can be accessed as http://servername:8080. Is there a way for me to make it work at http://servername:8080/hudson instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hudson internally uses [winstone](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/), so [its command line syntax applies](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/#commandLine).

(Source: [Starting and Accessing Hudson](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Starting+and+Accessing+Hudson))

Comment: --prefix=/hudson is what I was looking for. Thank you!